# How to change file timestamp from CMake?

Tags: cmake

I'm generating .pro files for QtCreator from a CMake script. A file in the project is to be generated later using a QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS instruction (the file is re-generated from other ones using an external tool only if it is older than them).

- To make sure the file to be generated is imported in QtCreator project without warning, I need to create it (else QtCreator reports warnings while parsing the .pro file).
- To make sure the file gets generated upon first compilation, I need to change the timestamp to be very old (older than any input file used to generate it). This is needed for QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS to consider the file as needing to be re-generated.

To do so, I do:

```
file(WRITE ${output_file_path} "To be generated..." )
execute_process( COMMAND touch.exe ${output_file_path} -t 0001010101 )
```

But, the `execute_process( COMMAND touch.exe ${output_file_path} -t 0001010101 )` takes a while. I have hundreds of files like that in my project and commenting this `execute_process` line divides my CMake generation time by 2 (0m45s vs 1m30s). I bet the execution of an external process is slowing things down....

Is there any way to change a file timestamp using pure CMake commands?

Comment: It's better to use cmake builtin commands: `execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${output_file_path} -t 0001010101)`. Can't you touch all the files in one command?

Comment: @KamilCuk: You hsould post this as an answer. Even if using cmake builtin command does not actually speed things up, it answers the question. And touching many files at once is actually a good way to speed things up, made me save a few seconds....

Answer (score 0):

cmake builtin commands are the preferred way. You can `touch` files by using:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${output_file_path} -t 0001010101)
```

This also works in any platform, independent if linux or windows.

If you have 'hundreds of files' you can touch them in one statement by providing touch command with multiple arguments, thus saving time on running make/build system commands (less dependencies to resolve for cmake build system :) .

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that `execute_process( COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${output_file_path} -t 0001010101 )` does not modify the file timestamp (Im' under Windows and `${output_file_path}` has slashs...).

Comment: puff, right, i knew something is wrong. touch from cmake is too crude, it doesn't understand `-t` options. Probably it created files named `-t` and `0001010101`.

Comment: Dunno what it does, but it does not work in the end, with path using slashs or backslashs....

Comment: So probably the right answer is "unfortunatley, you can't do this with CMake built in command...." ;-)